# Converting Byte[] to Image

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I want to convert `byt[]` to `image` in client side. I have tried the below code but it isn't working. I receive the data1 value but not able to convert it to image.

Client Side :

```
function getPic(name) {
    $.post("/Chat/ProfliePic", {
        name : name+".png"
    }, function(data1, status) {
        alert(data1);
        $("#profImg").attr("src","data:image/png;base64," + data1);
    });
}
```

Server Side :

```
package servlets;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/ProfliePic")
public class ProfliePic extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ProfliePic() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    File f = new File("/Users/shilu/MyProject/Chat/Photo/" + name);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new java.io.FileInputStream(f));
    in.readFully(data);
    in.close();
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Please tell me where I went wrong...

Comment: Note that if you get errors you normally get a stacktrace as well and you should post it here.

Comment: Actually, I didn't get any errors as such...

Comment: Line  $("#profImg").attr("src","data:image/png;base64," + data1);, data1 needs to be encoded as base64, whereas you stream it from the server as byte[], either encode it on the client or the server. Note If you don't rely on POST you can just set the img src of the image tag

Comment: `but it isn't working` isn't that helpful either. You should provide as many details on what is not working, e.g. what do you expect and what do you get instead? what did you check already? etc.

Comment: @revau.lt ,Sorry I didn't understand . Can you give the code

Comment: There seems to be multiple issues, 1) you do a POST in your JS but your server seems to implement a GET, 2) Jquery Http call doesn't allow you to retrieve a blob, so you will also get something interpreted as a string and you won't be able to encode it as base64. Assuming you are actually implementing this with GET (doGet on server) replace getPic by this `function getPic(name) {
    $("#profImg").attr("src", "/Chat/ProfliePic" + name + ".png");
}`.  no need for the ajax call...

Comment: @revau.lt ,  `name + ".png"` is a parameter and cant just send like `"/Chat/ProfliePic" + name + ".png"`

Comment: `function getPic(name) { $("#profImg").attr("src", "/Chat/ProfliePic?name=" + name + ".png"); }` should work, pay attention however with your server code, itseems to me that one can read arbitrary files from your webserver ...

Comment: Yeah bro, It is working..Thx a lot